# How apply styles in React Shadow Root?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I use React Shadow Root and every component has its own styles how can I apply these styles?

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ReactShadowRoot>
                <Header/>
                <Content/>
                <Footer/>
            </ReactShadowRoot>
        )
    }
}

const app = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(app);
ReactDOM.render(<Main />, app);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the styled-components package:
[NPM Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components)

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const HeaderWithStyle = styled(Header)`
  background: red;
`;
```

Comment: And I need to copy all styles from my Header.scss to Main.tsx?

Comment: Yes, but you can also export the variables from a file called something like component.styles.jsx. Btw, styles-components has scss support.

Comment: I think it's not a good idea because I have to collect all styles from all components in Main.tsx. My goal is a component approach. Like, React app without ReactShadowRoot. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Yes, maybe you can try styling the components individually?

Comment: Do you mean wrap every component in ReactShadowRoot?

Comment: No, style every component induvidually

Comment: I figure out a better solution and wrote an article about how to create an extension with React using Shadow DOM, maybe for someone it saves time https://medium.com/@isa.ugurchiev/creating-a-chrome-extension-with-cd5ab1f6aca1